# AVD system path for run by other user

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, multi-user

I try to start emulator being a user A, while Android sdk is installed by user B. I export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT exactly to where it is
`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/B/Android-install-dir/sdk`
but get `PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/home/B/Android-install-dir/sdk]!` For the user B everything works.

How to make it working for other users?

Or how to organize shared resources properly?

Comment: What Operating System are you on?

Comment: Linux  1111111111